# Drop rows in Dataframe unless there are at least 3 cells with values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with multiple NaNs. 
How do I extract only the rows with 3 non-NaN values?

```
id,a,b,c,d,e,f,g...z
1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,...NaN
2,NaN,NaN,3,NaN,2,...NaN
3,NaN,NaN,1,2,3,NaN,...NaN

Return row 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), thresh does exactly what you want :

```
df.dropna(thresh=3,axis=1)
```

> thresh : int, default None int value : require that many non-NA values